# Show and hide text in modularized shiny app based on actionButton() and shinyJS()

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinyjs

In the modularized shiny app below Im trying to display a message when the app is loaded for first time and then when I click the `actionButton()` this message is being hidden using `shinyJs()` and the plots are displayed. But the message is not displayed from the beginning.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
# Some data
data<-structure(list(scientificName = c("Turdus merula Linnaeus, 1758", 
                                        "Passer domesticus (Linnaeus, 1758)", "Cantharellus cinereus (Pers.) Fr.", 
                                        "Flammulina fennae Bas", "Mycena crocata (Schrad.) P.Kumm.", 
                                        "Lepista luscina (Fr.) Singer", "Mycena permixta (Britzelm.) Sacc.", 
                                        "Rhodophyllus byssisedus (Pers.) Quel.", "Rhodophyllus porphyrophaeus (Fr.) J.E.Lange", 
                                        "Panaeolus rickenii Hora"), decimalLatitude = c(52.204429, 51.387818, 
                                                                                        52.176667, 50.066111, 49.179167, 49.419444, 52.3, 52.3, 49.419444, 
                                                                                        49.179167), decimalLongitude = c(21.189275, 19.62673, 19.088056, 
                                                                                                                         19.502778, 22.434722, 20.380556, 20.566667, 20.566667, 20.380556, 
                                                                                                                         22.434722)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
                                                                                                                                                    41L, 42L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                    ))
data$year<-c(1990,1989,2003,1990,1980,1990,1989,2003,1990,1980)
# Define the side panel UI and server
sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
    uiOutput(ns("ye")),
    uiOutput(ns("scient")),
    actionButton(ns("action"),"Submit")
  )
  
}

sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      # define a reactive and return it
      react<-eventReactive(input$action,{
        
        omited <-subset(data, data$scientificName %in% isolate(input$sci)&data$year %in% isolate(input$yea))
      })
      
      output$ye<-renderUI({
        pickerInput(
          inputId = session$ns("yea"),
          label = "Year", 
          choices = sort(unique(data$year),decreasing=F),
          selected = unique(data$year),
          multiple = T
          
        )
      })
      
      output$scient<-renderUI({
        data <-subset(data, data$year %in% input$yea)
        
        pickerInput(
          inputId = session$ns("sci"),
          label = "Scientific name", 
          choices = unique(data$scientificName),
          selected = unique(data$scientificName)[1], 
          
        )
      })
      
      counted<-eventReactive(input$action,{isolate(react()) %>% 
          group_by(year) %>% 
          summarise(count=isolate(n())
          )
        
      })
      return(list(react = react, counted = counted, sci = reactive(input$sci),yea=reactive(input$yea)))
    })
}
# In this case this server not needed but using uiOuput/renderUI in real case
# sideServer <- function(id) { moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) { })}

# Define the UI and server functions for the map
mapUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    leafletOutput(ns("map"))
  )
}

mapServer <- function(id, city) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$map<-renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet(data = city()) %>% addTiles() %>%
          addMarkers(~decimalLatitude, ~decimalLongitude, popup = ~as.character(scientificName), label = ~as.character(scientificName))
      })
    })
}

plotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    plotlyOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}
textUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("help_text"))
  )
}
plotServer <- function(id, city, sci,yea) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$plot<-renderPlotly({
        
        fig <- plot_ly(data=city(), x = ~as.factor(year), y = ~count, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers+lines')
        
        fig%>% layout(title = paste("Count of", sci(),"through the years"),
                      xaxis = list(title = "Years",tickangle=45),
                      yaxis = list (title = "Count"))
      })
    })
}
textServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$help_text <- renderUI({
        HTML("<b>Click 'Show plot' to show the plot.</b>")
      })
      
      
      observeEvent(input$action,{
        hide("help_text")
      })
    })
  
    
}
# Build ui & server and then run
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),
  dashboardBody(useShinyjs(),mapUI("mapUK"), plotUI("plotPl"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # use the reactive in another module
  city_input <- sideServer("side")
  textServer("textPL")
  mapServer("mapUK", city_input$react)
  plotServer("plotPl", city_input$counted, sci = city_input$sci,yea=city_input$yea)
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things are wrong:

- you use `renderUI()` but you have `verbatimTextOutput` in the UI part. You need to use `uiOutput()` instead
- you forgot to call `textUI("textPL")` in the UI part
- you want to hide the text when `input$action` is clicked, but this input is defined in another module. Therefore it has a different namespace and clicking it doesn't trigger `hide()`. You need to pass the "click" through modules. There's a similar post about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144903/how-to-pass-buttons-click-action-between-modules).

Next time, you should also provide a minimal example, there is a lot of code that is irrelevant to the problem here.

Here's the working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
# Some data
data<-structure(list(scientificName = c("Turdus merula Linnaeus, 1758", 
                                        "Passer domesticus (Linnaeus, 1758)", "Cantharellus cinereus (Pers.) Fr.", 
                                        "Flammulina fennae Bas", "Mycena crocata (Schrad.) P.Kumm.", 
                                        "Lepista luscina (Fr.) Singer", "Mycena permixta (Britzelm.) Sacc.", 
                                        "Rhodophyllus byssisedus (Pers.) Quel.", "Rhodophyllus porphyrophaeus (Fr.) J.E.Lange", 
                                        "Panaeolus rickenii Hora"), decimalLatitude = c(52.204429, 51.387818, 
                                                                                        52.176667, 50.066111, 49.179167, 49.419444, 52.3, 52.3, 49.419444, 
                                                                                        49.179167), decimalLongitude = c(21.189275, 19.62673, 19.088056, 
                                                                                                                         19.502778, 22.434722, 20.380556, 20.566667, 20.566667, 20.380556, 
                                                                                                                         22.434722)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
                                                                                                                                                    41L, 42L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                    ))
data$year<-c(1990,1989,2003,1990,1980,1990,1989,2003,1990,1980)
# Define the side panel UI and server
sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
    uiOutput(ns("ye")),
    uiOutput(ns("scient")),
    actionButton(ns("action"),"Submit")
  )
  
}

sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      # define a reactive and return it
      react<-eventReactive(input$action,{
        
        omited <-subset(data, data$scientificName %in% isolate(input$sci)&data$year %in% isolate(input$yea))
      })
      
      output$ye<-renderUI({
        pickerInput(
          inputId = session$ns("yea"),
          label = "Year", 
          choices = sort(unique(data$year),decreasing=F),
          selected = unique(data$year),
          multiple = T
          
        )
      })
      
      output$scient<-renderUI({
        data <-subset(data, data$year %in% input$yea)
        
        pickerInput(
          inputId = session$ns("sci"),
          label = "Scientific name", 
          choices = unique(data$scientificName),
          selected = unique(data$scientificName)[1], 
          
        )
      })
      
      counted<-eventReactive(input$action,{isolate(react()) %>% 
          group_by(year) %>% 
          summarise(count=isolate(n())
          )
        
      })
      return(list(react = react, counted = counted, sci = reactive(input$sci),yea=reactive(input$yea), btn = reactive(input$action)))
    })
}
# In this case this server not needed but using uiOuput/renderUI in real case
# sideServer <- function(id) { moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) { })}

# Define the UI and server functions for the map
mapUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    leafletOutput(ns("map"))
  )
}

mapServer <- function(id, city) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$map<-renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet(data = city()) %>% addTiles() %>%
          addMarkers(~decimalLatitude, ~decimalLongitude, popup = ~as.character(scientificName), label = ~as.character(scientificName))
      })
    })
}

plotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    plotlyOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}
textUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("help_text"))
  )
}
plotServer <- function(id, city, sci,yea) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$plot<-renderPlotly({
        
        fig <- plot_ly(data=city(), x = ~as.factor(year), y = ~count, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers+lines')
        
        fig%>% layout(title = paste("Count of", sci(),"through the years"),
                      xaxis = list(title = "Years",tickangle=45),
                      yaxis = list (title = "Count"))
      })
    })
}
textServer <- function(id, btn) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$help_text <- renderUI({
        HTML("<b>Click 'Show plot' to show the plot.</b>")
      })
      
      
      observeEvent(btn(),{
        hide("help_text")
      })
    })
  
  
}
# Build ui & server and then run
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),
  dashboardBody(useShinyjs(),textUI("textPL"), mapUI("mapUK"), plotUI("plotPl"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # use the reactive in another module
  city_input <- sideServer("side")
  textServer("textPL", btn = city_input$btn)
  mapServer("mapUK", city_input$react)
  plotServer("plotPl", city_input$counted, sci = city_input$sci,yea=city_input$yea)
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```